# Javascript, Could you check my syntax please?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
javascript:If(document.getElementById('troop_confirm_go') != null){
    alert('true');
    return true;
  } else{
    alert('false');
    return false;
  }
```

Is there anything wrong with this syntax? I'm trying to run it on a page but it isn't showing either of the alerts, even if i try different pages with different buttons e.t.c. So it isn't something wrong with the page I want to run it on. (i'm testing this through the URL bar of my browser, and have tried both chrome and firefox, both yielding the same results)

Comment: Try formatting your code in a readable form first.

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive. `If` does not exist. `if`, on the other hand, does.

Comment: Ahhh, Thanks so much, sorry about forgetting to format it, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Frederic has already spotted your main error, but for future use, JSLint is your friend: http://www.jslint.com/ (enable "Assume Browser" and perhaps add alert into the predefined box) to avoid most common errors

Comment: @HeavenCore: You can also click the "Assume console, alert, ..." button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive, use `if`.

Answer (score 0):

here is something that works, you can start from:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function btnOnclick() {
                if(document.getElementById('troop_confirm_go') != null) {
                    alert('true');
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('false');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="btnOnclick()" value="button"/>
    </body>
</html>
```